# Reading data from doc file and displaying it on browser

Tags: php

I have uploaded a doc file in the database as blob type.
The doc file just contains my name: `Rohan Gala`

When I try to retrieve the data of the doc on browser using the code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "uname";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database_name";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT doc FROM customer where id=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
echo  $row["doc"];
?>
```

Then output is `PK!Ýü•7f [Content_Types].xml ¢( ´TËnÂ0¼Wê?D¾V‰¡‡ªªú8¶H¥`ì

and containing all such data

Also one thing:

When i am uploading the same doc file in html format it is showing output as required

Comment: post more if your code please, and note: not using mysqli class for MySQL stuff in PHP is deprecated

Comment: doc file as in Microsoft's proprietary file format? You'll need a DOC reader for that.

Comment: How to go about with the doc reader?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if your data only contains text

```
$sql = "SELECT CONVERT(doc USING utf8) FROM customer where id=1";
```

Comment: you are trying to output an xml file? if that is the case try this instead    header("Content-type: text/xml");   echo  $row["doc"];

Comment: trying to output microsoft doc file

Comment: Sadly you will need to use external library files to read it, PHP alone does not support .doc files